# What's the intake range is for a rotarycraft jet turbine?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am messing around with rotarycraft on my minecraft install. I am running a gas turbine to experiment with. I have read that you will get sucked in to the front of it while its operating, I have also found out the hard way.

What I am trying to figure out is what is the radius of the intake. I wanted to mark it with blocks so I can make sure people don't walk into it on my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, this region can be mapped out since item entities are affected by the suction but aren't destroyed and don't damage the turbine.  The image below was my attempt to map out the safe region - any item entity thrown into a dangerous area was sucked through and deposited ~13 blocks down the other end of the turbine.

[image]

As you can see, the dangerous region extends backward about 8.5 blocks and seems to be aligned with the centers of blocks as opposed to the edges.  The vertical extent is a bit harder to test, but the volume appears to resemble more of a square-based pyramid than a cone.  Keep in mind that contact with the top or sides of the turbine itself also counts as being sucked through.

Comment: Awesome! This perfectly answers my question. And the picture is a huge help too.

Comment: Yeah that thing is both awesome and terrifying to use. On one server it hungered for the flesh of players more than I care to admit.

Comment: a few fences will save a lot of flesh

Comment: I got confirmation from the mod author. The engine is in a 8 block step pyramid. So this takes care of the "how high" question too.

Comment: I tested this on the FTB Horizons pack, so it might actually be a configurable range with a default of 8.  Keep that in mind, as my image does appear to show a range a tiny bit larger than that.  I definitely verified that anything thrown on the row of gold blocks will get sucked in.